# CouchDB (Cloudant) Complex Keys

Tags: key, couchdb, cloudant, nosql

I have a view which returns the following data:

```
https://domain/db/_design/designdoc/_view/view

{"total_rows":3,"offset":0,"rows":[
{"id":"test1","key":[2015,2,18,1,33,27],"value":null},
{"id":"test3","key":[2015,2,20,1,33,27],"value":null},
{"id":"test2","key":[2016,2,19,1,33,27],"value":null}
]}
```

Querying a specific key works, for example:

```
https://domain/db/_design/designdoc/_view/view?key=[2015,2,20,1,33,27]

{"total_rows":3,"offset":2,"rows":[
{"id":"test3","key":[2015,2,20,1,33,27],"value":null}
]}
```

However, querying over a range always returns all three "rows". What am I doing wrong?

```
https://domain/db/_design/designdoc/_view/view?startKey=[2015,2,20,1,33,27]

{"total_rows":3,"offset":0,"rows":[
{"id":"test1","key":[2015,2,18,1,33,27],"value":null},
{"id":"test3","key":[2015,2,20,1,33,27],"value":null},
{"id":"test2","key":[2016,2,19,1,33,27],"value":null}
]}
```

Another example:

```
https://domain/db/_design/designdoc/_view/view?startKey=[2015,2,18,1,33,27]&endKey=[2015,2,20,1,33,27]

{"total_rows":3,"offset":0,"rows":[
{"id":"test1","key":[2015,2,18,1,33,27],"value":null},
{"id":"test3","key":[2015,2,20,1,33,27],"value":null},
{"id":"test2","key":[2016,2,19,1,33,27],"value":null}
]}
```

Answer (score 0):

Found the answer. The following works:

```
https://domain/db/_design/designdoc/_view/view?startkey=[2015,2,18,1,33,27]&endkey=[2015,2,20,1,33,27]

{"total_rows":3,"offset":1,"rows":[
{"id":"test1","key":[2015,2,18,1,33,27],"value":null},
{"id":"test3","key":[2015,2,20,1,33,27],"value":null}
]}
```

What is the difference between this example and the earlier ones? In this example I specified the query arguments as "startkey" and "endkey". Previously I incorrectly specified them as "startKey" and "endKey" (note the capital K). A hard lesson learned.